# Visual Studio 2008 + MOSS 2007 Unknown Error

Tags: 2007, visual-studio

Anyone can give me any insight on the following error:

[image]

By default, it should display the following:

[image]

because I was following the instruction in here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297200%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: I know I've said this before, but you should [turn Off CustomErrors and then it will help you debug what the actual error is](http://stevepietrek.com/2007/07/28/turn-off-sharepoint-custom-error-messages/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found as a comment by Kit.